# Bacnet on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, bacnet, bacnet4j

Currently I am working on simulation of SCADA system using bacnet protocol for network communication with my Raspberrry Pi for my final year project.

Current status: Raspberry Pi 2 able to run openplc (act like PLC)
done installing ScadaBR (act like SCADA system)

Current issue: How would I implement bacnet protocol for data link to make connection between both Raspberry Pi and my workstation?

I tried to research on bacnet stack protocol, implement some opensource but there is no luck. But I using the demo of youtube video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TJIrnAPsw4).
It making raspberry pi act as a bacnet server. the code is working perfectly. How can I find a bacnet protocol (client version) running on my Raspberry Pi.

here are some question I unable to source:

Which bacnet stack able to control the bacnet communication between PLC (Raspberry Pi) and ScadaBR?

How Raspberry Pi (openPLC preinstalled) communicate with ScadaBR?

use which bacnet stack to implement both workstation.

Answer (score 2):

The [BACpypes](https://github.com/JoelBender/bacpypes) library is written Python and runs on a variety of platforms, if you still have some time before the end of the term for your final project, contact me (the author) and maybe we can make something work.  I see that your question is tagged with Java, but maybe you have other options.